# Run php shell_exec in background

Tags: php

I had a file

run.php

the code is as followed

```
<?php

$shell_cmd = '/usr/bin/aria2c --on-bt-download-complete ./hook.sh "http://sometorrent.com/file.torrent"';

shell_exec($shell_cmd .' 2>&1 > out.log');

echo $shell_cmd;
?>
```

I tried run this script via website which is

```
http://mywebsite.com/run.php
```

My browser continue loading buffering sort of, until the torrent finish, how do i run in background so it execute right away in background.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$shell_cmd = '/usr/bin/aria2c --on-bt-download-complete ./hook.sh "http://sometorrent.com/file.torrent"';

shell_exec($shell_cmd .' > out.log &');

echo $shell_cmd;
?>
```

This will run the shell command in background

Comment: I tried your solution but my program still run with buffering till the script execute finish.